# With module ptext in pygame empty """ strings return an error

Tags: python, text, pygame

I am attempting to give player input, and when a player provides no input(or just line breaks) into a triple quote string, when ptext tries to draw it, it errors out. This seems like a flaw in the library and if so any strategies to get around it would be appreciated.

```
cutText = """


"""

ptext.draw(cutText, (100, -75), fontname = "resources/FontAndText/Roboto-Thin.ttf", color="#000000", gcolor =  "#ffa500", fontsize = 20)
```

https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text

Comment: For what it's worth — as it probably has no bearing on the bug you have supposedly found — the contents of sample `cutText` shown is _not_ an empty string. Do a `print(repr(cutText))` to prove that.

Comment: For actually help, you would need to provide a executable [mre] others could run that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pygame-text author here. I believe you encountered a bug which has just recently been fixed. Can you get the latest version and try again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but apparently I can reply post. I tried to reproduce the problem by pasting your code into the example.py that is supplied with ptext.py. The only error I encountered was related to the font and the strategy to get around it was to delete 'fontname = "resources/FontAndText/Roboto-Thin.ttf",' from the call to ptext.draw().